# Small cross browser compatibility CSS issue

Tags: html, css, joomla, cross-browser, joomla-template

Any one able to help me identify this cross browser CSS issue

http://bit.ly/HC1c2u

In firefox the "get connected" area shows as intended, in others it isn't any help appreciated

Effected HTML

```
 <div style="font-size:14px; width:1000px;" id="yjsg3">
    <div style="width:100%;" class="yjsgxhtml" id="user1">
    <div class="yjsquare">
<div class="yjsquare_in"><div class="on-youevents ltr" id="community-wrap"><!-- js_top --> <!-- begin: #cFrontpageWrapper -->
 <div id="cFrontpageWrapper">
 <div class="greybox">
 <div>
 <div>
 <div class="cFrontpageSignup"><!-- Start the Intro text -->
 <div class="cFrontPageLeft">
 <div class="introduction">
 <h1>Get Connected!</h1>
 <ul id="featurelist">
 <li>Connect and expand your network</li>
 <li>View profiles and add new friends</li>
 <li>Share your photos and videos</li>
 <li>Create your own group or join others</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="joinbutton"><a title="JOIN US NOW, IT'S FREE!" href="/rhythm365/social/register.html" id="joinButton"> JOIN US NOW, IT'S FREE! </a></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- End Intro text --> <!-- Start the Login Form -->
 <div class="cFrontPageRight">
 <div class="loginform"><form name="login" method="post" action="/rhythm365/social.html" id="form-login">
 <h2>Members Login</h2>
 <label> Username<br> <input type="text" name="username" class="inputbox frontlogin" id="username"> </label> <label> Password<br> <input type="password" name="password" class="inputbox frontlogin" id="password"> </label> <label for="remember"> <input type="checkbox" alt="Remember me" value="yes" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me      </label>
 <div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px 0 5px;"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="button" id="submit"> <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option"> <input type="hidden" value="user.login" name="task"> <input type="hidden" value="L3JoeXRobTM2NS9zb2NpYWwvcHJvZmlsZS5odG1s" name="return"> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="b8f1cd79c6f1e95ecd9c177eec53d705"></div>
 <span> <a href="/rhythm365/component/users/?view=reset" class="login-forgot-password">          <span>Forgot your Password?</span></a><br> <a href="/rhythm365/component/users/?view=remind" class="login-forgot-username"><span>Forgot your Username?</span></a> </span>      <br> <a href="/rhythm365/social/register/activation.html" class="login-forgot-username">      <span>Resend activation code?</span> </a></form></div>
 </div>
 <!-- End the Login form -->
 <div class="jsClr">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div></div>
 </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably due to the specificity of your headings...http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is semicolon missing after the import rule in file '/templates/youevents/css/custom.css'

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your reset.css, you have font-family: inherit;

Delete this and you should be good to go...

```
#community-wrap h1, #community-wrap h2, #community-wrap h3, #community-wrap h4, #community-wrap h5, #community-wrap h6 {
border: 0 none;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
font-style: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
margin: 0;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
```

}

You could probably just delete this whole chunk

Firebug is an invaluable tool for web development, I suggest you add this to firefox and you'll be able to debug far more quickly

Comment: I deleted that code block but it made no difference, im not to sure why a inherited font would make that much of a difference